# SSLHandshakeException on WebSocket connection with OkHttp3

Tags: java, android, ssl, websocket, okhttp

I'm trying to connect to WSS websocket using OkHttp3, but I got in `onFailure()` method of my `WebSocketListener` in particular the Exception said:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed

Now, I'm using this code to connect to WSS

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder().url("wss://mywssdomain").build();
WebSocketListenerCP listener = new WebSocketListenerCP(); //My listener, do nothing only override methods
WebSocket ws = client.newWebSocket(request, listener);
client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();
```

I've read a lot about issue with Android < Lollipop but I'm on Nougat anyway I've tried to nuke all SSL certificate by doing (before connection)

```
SSLCertificateHandler.nuke();
```

**SSLCertificateHandler class**

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class SSLCertificateHandler {

    /**
     * Enables https connections
     */
    public static void nuke() {
        try {
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    X509Certificate[] myTrustedAnchors = new X509Certificate[0];
                    return myTrustedAnchors;
                }

                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
            } };

            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

And I also tried to add connectionSpecs to my OkHttp3 client

```
ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
        .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
        .cipherSuites(
                CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA)
        .build();

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec)).build();
Request request = new Request.Builder().url("wss://mywssdomain").build();
WebSocketListenerCP listener = new WebSocketListenerCP();
WebSocket ws = client.newWebSocket(request, listener);
client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();
```

I'm not understand

1) Why I get SSLHandshakeException?

2) Is right connection to WSS?

Comment: what u did in `nuke()` is a bad practice for ssl security. also make sure you can access the domain using http and https from web browser. You might also want to share the stack trace of exception.

Comment: Hi Michele Lacorte i am also facing the same issue. Any solution ?